# Server-Sent Events with Play: response only received when process killed

Tags: scala, playframework, server-sent-events, chunked-encoding

I'm trying to get the sample webapp [**play-streaming-scala**](https://github.com/playframework/play-streaming-scala) to run and in some circumstances I get a weird behavior.

I've got the app running directly on port 80 of some host and I'm checking the output with `curl -iv --raw http://somehost/scala/eventSource/liveClock`.

What I'm expecting is something like this:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 195.176.3.71...
* Connected to somehost (0.0.0.0) port 80 (#0)
> GET /scala/eventSource/liveClock HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.39.0
> Host: somehost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8
< Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2017 13:24:55 GMT
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2017 13:24:55 GMT

< 
10
data: 14 24 56


10
data: 14 24 56


10
data: 14 24 56
```

etc., and clearly see the chunks appear one after the other as time goes by.

Now, on some machines, this works well. On some others on campus, this fails. `curl` only shows this and then stops:

```
*   Trying 195.176.3.71...
* Connected to somehost (0.0.0.0) port 80 (#0)
> GET /scala/eventSource/liveClock HTTP/1.1
> Host: somehost
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

Now the interesting thing is: if I kill the webapp on the host, `curl` suddenly “catches up” and spits all the chunks together, closing the connection like this:

```
10
data: 14 35 20


* transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
* Closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

What can be causing the behavior? What on earth is going on and intercepting these events? Is there any way I can “force flush” something from the Play response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the local “hidden” proxy set up automatically by OS X's parental controls system is not forwarding chunked responses properly, thus making a system based on Server-Sent Events inoperable. A shame.